# How to assign a directory to PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, python-2.x

New to python and PyCharm, but trying to use if for an online course.

After opening an assignment `.py` document (attached image), I get an error message if I open the python console:

> Error:Cannot start process, the working directory '\c:...\python_lab.py' is not a directory.

Obviously, it is not - it is a python file, but I don't know how to address the problem.

How can I assign a working directory that is functional from within PyCharm, or in general, what is the meaning of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new project
2. Create new py file in your project or copy your file to under the project directory

Second option would be *import existing project* by selecting a directory where you have your python file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your default working directory is a `.tmp` folder. Best way to fix this is to create a new project, just make sure it's not pointing to a `.tmp` directory.